# How to pull docker image to GCP Cloud

Tags: cloud

I want to pull one docker image to the GCP with the CLI command. But I am new to GCP CLI. Can anyone tell me, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to configure the GCP CLI in your system before you can use gcloud docker command to pull images to GCP.

```
$ gcloud docker --pull gcr.io/google-containers/pause:1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems for the versions of `gcloud` > 18.03, `gcloud docker` sub-commands have been removed. However, this should work:

```bash
gcloud auth configure-docker
docker pull gcr.io/google-containers/pause:1.0
```